# In R how do I lable the fill (or group) of a geom_line graph with multiple lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have the following code, based on a dataframe that has rows for each year and one of six newspapers, and then two columns with numbers.
For example:
year|medium_name|n_transsexu|n_transgende
2012|New York Times|15|22
2012|Daily Mail|10|20
2013|New York Times|10|12
etc.

With the following code, I want to make a geom_line graph showing the change of the two number columns over time, but sepeate for each medium:

```
yeardf_medium %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, group = medium_name)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = n_transsexu, col = "transsexuell etc.")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = n_transgende, col = "transgender etc.")) +
    labs(title = "Nennung spezifischer Schlüsselwörter über Zeit (nach Medium)",
         subtitle = "transsexuell/Transsexualismus etc. vs. transgender/Transgenderismus etc",
         x = "Jahr",
         y = "Anzahl Nennungen")
```

It results into the following graph:
[graph with no lables for group lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvbTG.png)

As you can see, the graph shows different lines for the mediums (as I intended with group = medium_name; it would also work with fill = medium_name).
But I can't differentiate between the different mediums, as the colors are just changed based on the columns with the numbers.
How can I add a legend for the group (or fill)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solutions are based on this generated data:

```
year <- rep(c(1995:2022), each = 3)
medium_name <- rep(c("New York Times", "Daily Mail", "News Paper"), times = 28)
n_transsexu <- abs(year-1995 + sample(c(-20:-1), 84, replace = TRUE))
n_transgende <- abs(year-1995  + sample(c(-20:-1), 84, replace = TRUE))

yeardf_medium <- data.frame(year, medium_name, n_transsexu, n_transgende)
```

The simpelst solution to color for medium_name is to change "`group = medium_name`" to "`col = medium_name`" and to remove the two "col = " statements in your `geom_line()`:

```
yeardf_medium %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=year, col = medium_name)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = n_transsexu)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = n_transgende)) +
      labs(title = "Nennung spezifischer Schlüsselwörter über Zeit (nach Medium)",
           subtitle = "transsexuell/Transsexualismus etc. vs. transgender/Transgenderismus etc",
           x = "Jahr",
           y = "Anzahl Nennungen")
```

[Graph with colors for every Medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r64CB.png)

However, this graph looks really messy and you cannot differentiate between your keywords (transgender vs. transsexual). You could achieve this by adding different line types for each keyword. To do this I suggest you to transform your dataframe into long-format with the function `pivot_longer()`. Generally, if you are working with ggplot2 I recommend to use your data in long-format.

```
yeardf_medium %>%
  pivot_longer(c(n_transsexu,n_transgende), names_to = "keyword", values_to = "n") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n))+
  geom_line(aes(col = medium_name, linetype = keyword), size = 1.5)+
  labs(title = "Nennung spezifischer Schlüsselwörter über Zeit (nach Medium)",
       subtitle = "transsexuell/Transsexualismus etc. vs. transgender/Transgenderismus etc",
       x = "Jahr",
       y = "Anzahl Nennungen")
```

[Graph with different line types for every Medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBXfs.png)

However, this still looks quite messy. Therefore, I would recommend to use `facet_wrap()` to split up your plot for either each keyword or each medium:

```
yeardf_medium %>%
  pivot_longer(c(n_transsexu,n_transgende), names_to = "keyword", values_to = "n") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n))+
  geom_line(aes(col = medium_name), size = 1.5)+
  labs(title = "Nennung spezifischer Schlüsselwörter über Zeit (nach Medium)",
       subtitle = "transsexuell/Transsexualismus etc. vs. transgender/Transgenderismus etc",
       x = "Jahr",
       y = "Anzahl Nennungen")+
  facet_wrap(~keyword)
```

[Graph split up for each keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf6df.png)

```
yeardf_medium %>%
  pivot_longer(c(n_transsexu,n_transgende), names_to = "keyword", values_to = "n") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n))+
  geom_line(aes(col = keyword), size = 1.5)+
  labs(title = "Nennung spezifischer Schlüsselwörter über Zeit (nach Medium)",
       subtitle = "transsexuell/Transsexualismus etc. vs. transgender/Transgenderismus etc",
       x = "Jahr",
       y = "Anzahl Nennungen")+
  facet_wrap(~medium_name)
```

[Graph split up for each medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW5c1.png)

Comment: Thanks for your indepth answer.
I have since used the facet-wrap option on my graphs, and on other graphs as well. But have realized it changes the graphs significantly. For some other data, I have three code chunks that produce different graphs. One uses a fill in the ggplot(aes()), one uses the facet_wrap at the end and a third uses both. The one with just facet wrap has bars going as high as 150, when actually the highest number in the data set is 46, which is reflected in the graph produced without the facet line and the one with both the fill and facet line. How can this be?

Comment: `fill =` tells ggplot to split up the data and fill the graph with different colors for the specific variable you entered in `fill = `. If you do not specify anything in either `fill = `, `group = ` or `color = `, ggplot will use the whole data. 

For example: You have two persons: A and B.  A has an IQ = 110, B has an IQ = 85. If you use `ase(fill = person)` you will get two bars in different colors for each person. If you do not specify the `fill = ` or any other grouping parameter you will get one bar with 195. Keep in mind this can change depending on the`geom_` you're using.